# Can't see custom keyboard in Safari of iOS8.1 simulator

Tags: ios, ios8, custom-keyboard

After update to Xcode 6.1, I lost my custom keyboard in Safari of iOS8.1 simulator. But it's still come in photo app. Photo app can switch to my custom keyboard, but Safari still display English and Emoji, other system keyboard like Arabic also not work. I reset simulator but not work.
It's look nothing change in Safari in iOS8.1.I try to clear DerivedData folder but it no help.
I remove Xcode and reinstall from Appstore, not work too.

I must test on my device, too strange.
Does anyone have same issue? please help how to solve this.

Comment: Yes, I have exactly the same issue! Since 6.1 update Safari and (what's MUCH worse) any of my own apps are stuck with English and Emoji keyboards. Spotlight and photos works fine.

Comment: Calendar works too on mine, but all other apps don't work. I deleted the Emoji Keyboard, but nothing ...

Comment: Having the same issue. Anybody reported it?

Comment: The only question here, is "Does anyone have the same issue?" The correct answer is "Yes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue. From the [release notes for XCode 6.1.1](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6.1.1_gm_seed_rucg3e/xcode_6.1.1_gm_seed_release_notes.pdf):

> Localization and Keyboard settings, including 3rd party keyboards,
>   are not correctly honored by Safari, Maps, and developer apps in the
>   iOS 8.1 Simulator. [NSLocale currentLocale] returns en_US and only the
>   English and Emoji keyboards are available. (18418630, 18512161)

The suggested work around is to use another app, such as Contacts, for which the keyboard *does* display correctly in the simulator.

Answer (score -1):

You may have to stop your physical keyboard from taking control. From the Simulator's Mac menu:

```
Hardware -> Keyboard -> (uncheck) Connect Hardware Keyboard
```

Comment: This way no help! Only for keyboard not come up. The keyboard come up in Photo app but still English one in Safari, can't switch to custom keyboard after select.

Answer (score -2):

The text above actually only contains a simple question

> "Does anyone else have this issue".

The correct answer is

> "Yes other people have the same issue."

Comment: @iAn Stackoverflow has a deliberate question and answer format, it is not a discussion forum. It would be better if you don't rely on other people to fix up your question.