# IOS simulator UITextField without Chinese keyboard

Tags: ios, simulator

As the title description, even i added Chinese keyboard, there's no Chinese keyboard in my app. But the system has Chinese keyboard.
**See below**:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check your settings in the Default iPhone app

Comment: Sorry what do you mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS8.1 Simulator always uses US keyboard layout despite german hardware keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-keyboard)

Comment: If you click the home button there you have an app called settings. Get in then general->keyboard

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. Answer is here: [Can't see custom keyboard in Safari of iOS8.1 simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492492/cant-see-custom-keyboard-in-safari-of-ios8-1-simulator)

and here is the workaround (near the bottom): [iOS8.1 Simulator always uses US keyboard layout despite german hardware keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-keyboard)